# How to change element value by comparing another xml using xslt

Tags: xml, rest, xslt, web, xslt-1.0

I have below xml 1 and xml2. I want compare `</publication>` from xml1 with xml2 and update `<price>` in xml1 with the value present in xml2.Please help me out.

I have stored whole xml2 in one variable.I got a template which looks for match="book",inside this i parse it through the xml2 variable and match for publication with publication in xml1.If matches,call template which match="price" but
its adding new  tag inside  but not updating existing one.

### XML-1

```
<books>
<book>
<name>abc</name>
<publication>triangle</publication>
<price></price>
</book>
<book>
<name>def</name>
<publication>rectangle</publication>
<price></price>
</book>
</books>
```

### xml-2

```
<resource>
<prices>
<publication>triangle</publication>
<price>100</price>
<prices>
<prices>
<publication>rectangle</publication>
<price>200</price>
<prices>
</resource>
```

expected output

```
<books>
    <book>
    <name>abc</name>
    <publication>triangle</publication>
    <price>100</price>
    </book>
    <book>
    <name>def</name>
    <publication>rectangle</publication>
    <price>200</price>
    </book>
    </books>
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the XSLT you have currently tried? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
<xsl:variable name="book1" select="document('file:////C://mohit//Untitled23.xml')/resource" as="node()"/>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:copy>  
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//price">
<xsl:variable name="pub" select="preceding-sibling::publication[1]"/>
<xsl:variable name="bk" select="$book1//price[preceding-sibling::publication[1] = $pub][1]"/>
<price>
<xsl:value-of select="$bk"/>
</price>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="back" select="if (doc-available('b.xml')) then doc('b.xml') else ()"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="book">
<book>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</book>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="name">
<name>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</name>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="publication">
<publication>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</publication>
<price>
<xsl:if test="$back//publication = .">
<xsl:value-of select="$back//prices[. = publication]/price"/>
</xsl:if>
</price>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```